# Iterating over key/value pairs in a dict sorted by keys

Tags: python

I have the following code, which just print the key/value pairs in a dict (the pairs are sorted by keys):

```
for word, count in sorted(count_words(filename).items()):
    print word, count
```

However, calling `iteritems()` instead of `items()` produces the same output

```
for word, count in sorted(count_words(filename).iteritems()):
    print word, count
```

Now, which one should I choose in this situation? I consulted the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) but it doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In Python 2.x both will give you the same result. The difference between them is that `items` constructs a list containing the entire contents of the dictionary whereas `iteritems` gives you an iterator that fetches the items one at a time. In general `iteritems` is a better choice because it doesn't require so much memory. But here you are sorting the result so it probably won't make any significant difference in this situation. If you are in doubt `iteritems` is a safe bet. If performance really matters then measure both and see which is faster.

In Python 3.x `iteritems` has been removed and `items` now does what `iteritems` used to do, solving the problem of programmers wasting their time worrying about which is better. :)

As a side note: if you are counting occurrences of words you may want to consider using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of a plain dict (requires Python 2.7 or newer).

Comment: +1 Wow! I didn't know something like this existed. Very handy!

Answer (score 10):

As per Marks answer: In Python 2, use `iteritems()`, in Python 3 use `items()`.

And additionally; If you need to support both (and don't use `2to3`) use:

```
counts = count_words(filename)
for word in sorted(counts):
     count = counts[word]
```