# why does dictionary need those 'iter' methods?

Tags: python, iterator

Assume `mydict` is a Python dictionary.

```
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

I can use `items` to iterate its elements:

```
for k,v in mydict.items():
    print k,v
```

Or use `iteritems`:

```
for k,v in mydict.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

what's the difference? I think the philosophy of python is 'only one way to do'?

Comment: This has [been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4550645/589206) before with a very detailed accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3 the `dict.iter...()` methods have been removed and replace the normal ones.

They existed as iterators were added into the language after dictionaries, so `dict.items()` returns a list. The `dict.iter...()` methods were added to allow people to make more efficient programs (as iterators are lazy), but also not break compatibility with old programs that expected a list.

As Python 3 broke compatibility, this was fixed. (The old usage of `dict.iter()` can be generated with `list(dict.iter())`. Note that in Python 3 `dict.items()` actually returns a [dictionary view](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) - which can be iterated over, but also provides other functionality.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2, `mydict.items` returns a *new list*. Using `iteritems` saves memory, and is more efficient.

```
>>> d = dict((f, r) for f, r in zip(range(10000), reversed(range(10000))))
>>> %timeit for i in d.iteritems(): i
1000 loops, best of 3: 456 us per loop
>>> %timeit for i in d.items(): i
1000 loops, best of 3: 811 us per loop
```

But (as others have pointed out) `items` was left unchanged in Python 2 for backwards-compatibility.

In Python 3, this problem is fixed; `items` returns a "[view](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)" (which is neither a list nor an iterator, but is rather "a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries" that changes when the dictionary changes) and `iteritems` no longer exists, nor do its cousins `itervalues` and `iterkeys`.

Answer (score 4):

> I think the philosophy of python is 'only one way to do'?

The reason both `items()` and `iteritems()` exist is historic:

1. Initially, only `items()` existed. It returned a *list*.
2. In Python 2.2, `iteritems()` got introduced. It returned an *iterator*.
3. In Python 2.7, `viewitems()` got introduced. It returned a [*view*](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).
4. Python 3 took the opportunity to tidy this up: `iteritems()` and `items()` got dropped and `viewitems()` got renamed to `items()`.

The reason `iteritems()` and `viewitems()` were added in 2.x as new functions instead of simply replacing `items()` was the desire to keep all 2.x releases backwards compatible.

Comment: `items()` in python 3 returns a "view", which is NOT an iterator: It is basically a lazy list. To iterate over it, you need `iter(d.keys())` etc. Check out PEP 3106.

Comment: @alexis: I've already fixed that. Please see the updated answer.